# Jquery code for the dynamic auto suggest values based on dropdown slection

Tags: jquery

> I have multiple dynamic dropdowns and its related textboxes. Whenever
>   any dynamic drop-down option selection is changed, its related textbox auto
>   suggest values need to be changed.

```
var source = [
{"idtype": "1", "idnumber": "In21","Company": "12345"},{"idtype": "2", "idnumber": "In24","Company": "12323"},
{"idtype": "3", "idnumber": "In22","Company": "12323"},{"idtype": "1", "idnumber": "In25","Company": "12323"},
{"idtype": "2", "idnumber": "In23","Company": "12367"},{"idtype": "3", "idnumber": "In26","Company": "12323"} ];
```

Dropdown values are idtype from the source data. Auto-suggest values for the textbox is related company names.

Comment: And question is?

Comment: you should add some more code